# Node.js - Parsing Images from JSON Object Reference

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, api

I am parsing JSON data from a remote API. The particular endpoint I am using returns all the values I want like title, description, summary and cover. I was hoping the cover field would be a string with the jpg url, but instead returns an object reference id. If you make another request and pass the object ID, the url string is there. How can I parse the image data without making another call to a different endpoint? I am using the IGDB API and following their documentation.
Here is my code

```
    const axios = require('axios');
axios({
  url: "https://api-v3.igdb.com/games",
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'user-key': 'xxxx'
  },
  data: "fields name,summary,url,cover,popularity;sort popularity desc;limit 13;"
})
  .then(response => {
    /* GET home page. */
    router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
      res.render('index', { pageId: 'index',
                        title: 'Homepage',
                        cards: homeCards
        });
    });
    //Iterate through the JSON array
    let r = response.data;
    console.log(response.data); 
    for (i=0; i<r.length; ++i){
      //Store json values 
        var title = r[i].name;
        var description = r[i].summary;
        var link = r[i].url;
        var imageId = r[i].cover;
        //Push values onto homeCards
        homeCards.push({
          title: title,
          link: link,
          description: description,
        });
      }

  })
  .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
  });
```

I store the cover id in a variable imageId. How can I use this to show the corresponding object reference for each game?

Comment: According to their API documentation this is not possible. A second call will always be needed to the covers endpoint.

Comment: Gotcha, How would I go about making this call? Will I have another axios function nested in my current one? How will the program know which image belongs to which game?

Comment: I suggest using async/await instead of nesting promises.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of performing the two requests using async/await and matching the cover based on the gameId.

```js
const axios = require('axios');

(async () => {
  const links = (await axios({
      url: "https://api-v3.igdb.com/covers",
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'user-key': 'xxxx'
      },
      data: "fields game,url"
    }).catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    })).data

  const response = await axios({
    url: "https://api-v3.igdb.com/games",
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'user-key': 'xxxx'
    },
    data: "fields dlcs,name,summary,url,cover,popularity;sort popularity desc;limit 13;"
  }).catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
  })
       
  /* GET home page. */
  router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('index', { pageId: 'index',
                      title: 'Homepage',
                      cards: homeCards
      });
  });
  //Iterate through the JSON array
  let r = response.data;
  console.log(response.data); 
  for (i=0; i<r.length; ++i){
    //Store json values 
      var title = r[i].name;
      var description = r[i].summary;
      //Find the cover based on the game id
      var link = links.find(l => l.game === r[i].dlcs).url
      var imageId = r[i].cover;
      //Push values onto homeCards
      homeCards.push({
        title: title,
        link: link,
        description: description,
      });
    }
})()
```

Edit:
To answer your question in the comments. [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) takes a callback function as its first argument. In the code snippet above I have used an [ES6 Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to pass in as the callback to find which is equivalent to:

```
links.find(function(l) {
  var boolean = l.game === r[i].dlcs
  return boolean
}).url
```

Comment: I really like your answer, but I need help understanding how you find the cover based on the game ID. can you explain this line in more detail: var link = links.find(l => l.game === r[i].dlcs).url. Specifically the code in the paraenthesis

Comment: No worries. Arrow functions can look a bit strange.

Comment: After digging through the documentation more, I realized that there is no endpoint for images. Its just listed under references. On their github, they recommend using their api wrappers to parse images. Here is the link: https://github.com/igdb/igdb-api-node

Comment: The documentation mentions something called expanders which is used to combine multiple requests. I think this is what I'm looking for. I'll make some edit and get back to you guys if this is the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Hello all and thanks for the help. The answer was mush easier than I though and it was my bad when reading through the documentation. All you have to do is specify the sub field in the axios function.

```
data: "fields name,summary,url,cover,popularity,cover.url;sort popularity desc;limit 13;"
```

cover.url brings me the image url for each game